# What is significance of __GFP_HARDWALL in context of user pages(GFP_USER)?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I found in kernel source, __GFP_HARDWALL flag is mainly used for user pages(GFP_USER). The flag enforces the cpuset memory allocation policy. Can anyone tell me what is significance of __GFP_HARDWALL in context of  user pages(GFP_USER)? How does it make difference from GFP_KERNEL?